# Can I use Django templatetags on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, templatetags

My Django site has many templatetags directories, can I use Django templatetags on Google App Engine?

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770854/django-custom-template-tags-in-google-app-engine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes](http://daily.profeth.de/2008/04/using-custom-django-template-helpers.html).